# facebook api: how to avoid insecure sending alert?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Here the code

```
    $facebook =  new Facebook(
    array (
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $secret,
    )
`enter code here`);


    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if (!$user) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'redirect_url', $app_url    // SI ! sono due elementi, non è un array associativo !
        )
    );
    echo $loginUrl;
} else {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo "<pRE>" . print_r ($user_profile, true) . "</PRE>";
        $nome_completo = $user_profile["name"];
        $nome = $user_profile["first_name"];
        $cognnome = $user_profile["last_name"];
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e;
        $user = null;
    }


}
```

When I launch https://apps.facebook.com/575262285841594/ (**actually app is in sandbox mode !!!!**) I obtain a working (useless) app, but ... every time firefox warn me about the page ison https but i'm sending via insecure transmission ...

What must I do to avoid this !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a valid SSL certificate on your server in order to use https.
Facebook only accepts secure connections, so you will need to purchase a certificate

Comment: It have nothing to do with being in sandbox or not. The content is pulled from your server via https. If there is no certificate on your server, firefox will alert you that its insecure.
The alert has nothing to do with facebook.